# Define a keyword to call only on failure in robot framework

Tags: python, python-3.x, robotframework

Is there any way we can define in `setting` or any other part of robot code to call keyword immediately when we have a particular kind of failure?

We have `Test setup` and `Test Teardown`, which will run at the start as Test Setup or the end of the test case as Test Teardown, similar to that is there any way, we can define and call keyword based on failure

The problem with using Teardown is when we have 5 lines of robot code (Keywords) if the failure happens on the second line, it will skip the third, fourth, and fifth line and directly runs the Teardown *this is the issue for me in using Teardown*. If we have a failure in the second line, it will call the defined  keyword which needs to be run and then comes back and run third, fourth, and fifth line (Without Skipping).

Comment: Failed test case is failed test case. It seems to me that what you want to implement is ignoring errors and just pressing on with the execution. Is that a test case?

Comment: @pavelsaman ignoring is one part of it . It must ignore the failure ,but as there is a failure it must call specific keyword which we can defined in one place , so when ever there is a failure it will be called . I don't want to add it to every test case calling part . Keyword must be called automatically as there is a failure

Comment: Are you aware of the built-in keyword [Run keyword and continue on failure](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Continue%20On%20Failure)? You can use that, and then examine the status to know if you need to run the other keyword.

Comment: @BryanOakley yeah ! But the problem is I need to add this to all my test case . That will be lot of rework . So I was looking at something which can be defined at one place . Just like Test setup or Test Teardown

Comment: Lets say it is possible to run a keyword on failure, SeleniumLibrary does it for example. Even that no keyword will be executed from the original test beyond the failure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a [listener library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#library-listeners) you can implement such functionality. Create a keyword that will set the desired keyword to be executed on failure. Implement the `end_keyword` [listener](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#listener-version-2) function to detect when a keyword failure occurs.

Lastly execute the configured keyword using the `BuiltIn` library `run_keyword` function.

Example:

```python
from robot.api import logger
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn

class RunOnFailureLibrary(object):
    ROBOT_LISTENER_API_VERSION = 2
    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'GLOBAL'
    ROBOT_LIBRARY_VERSION = 0.1

    def __init__(self):
        self.ROBOT_LIBRARY_LISTENER = self
        self.keyword_to_run_on_faiure = None
        self.keyword_args = None

    def set_keyword_to_run_on_failure(self, keyword, *args):
        self.keyword_to_run_on_faiure = keyword
        if len(args) > 0:
            self.keyword_args = args
        
    def _end_keyword(self, name, attributes):
        if attributes['status'] == 'FAIL':
            logger.info(f"Running keyword:'{self.keyword_to_run_on_faiure}' on failure!")
            if self.keyword_args is None:
                BuiltIn().run_keyword(self.keyword_to_run_on_faiure)
            else:
                BuiltIn().run_keyword(self.keyword_to_run_on_faiure, *self.keyword_args)
        

globals()[__name__] = RunOnFailureLibrary
```

Usage:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    RunOnFailureLibrary
Suite Setup    Set Keyword To Run On Failure    Log Many    1    2   3

*** Test Cases ***
Test
    Log    1
    Log    2
    Fail   0
    Log    3
    Log    4
```

Result (run with `robot --pythonpath . test.robot`):

[image]

As I said in the comments, the rest of the test case still won't be executed. To achieve that you have to ignore the failure as others have suggested.